# URL rewrite and RegExp

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want the URL rewrite to result in this:

```
test.php?site=hi  --> www.domain.com/hi
test.php?site=hi&id=1  --> www.domain.com/hi/1
test.php?site=hi&cmd=test  --> www.domain.com/hi/test
test.php?site=hi&cmd=test&id=1  --> www.domain.com/hi/test/1
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't work. I am new at regular expressions, so there might be place for corrections:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?+([0-9]+)?/? test.php?site=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?+([a-zA-Z]+)?/?+([0-9]+)?/? test.php?site=$1&cmd=$2&id=$3
```

How should the RewriteRule be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/(\d+)/?$ /test.php?site=$1&cmd=$2&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ /test.php?site=$1&cmd=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ /test.php?site=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /test.php?site=$1 [L,QSA]
```